# unity c# shooter game stop cloning when player dies

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i'm making a game with a granny shooting ducks. I have the granny dieing 
after her lives are up but i'm trying to get the ducks to stop cloning when she
dies, so the game-over will appear, anyone? Im knew to this so any help would be grateful. can also give more code if needs

```
public class GrannyController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed;
    public int health = 10;
    public Text healthDisplay;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector2 moveVelocity;
    public int score;
    public GameObject gameOverPanel;


    public bool IsAlive()
    {
        return this.health > 0;
    }

    public void Die()
    {
        //StartCoroutine(DieCoroutine);
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        score = 0;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        healthDisplay.text = "Lives :" + health;

        if (health <= 0)
        {
            //SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
            GameOver();
        }

        {
            Vector2 moveInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
            moveVelocity = moveInput.normalized * speed;
        }
    }
    void FixedUpdate()

    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + moveVelocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }

    void GameOver()
    {
        CancelInvoke();
        gameOverPanel.SetActive(true);
    }
}

public class SpawnerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GrannyController player;
    public GameObject duck;
    public Transform[] spawnSpots;
    private float timeBtwSpawns;
    public float startTimeBtwSpawns;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        timeBtwSpawns = startTimeBtwSpawns;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (!player.IsAlive()) return; // Check if player is alive, stop if not

        timeBtwSpawns -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (timeBtwSpawns <= 0)
        {
            int randPos = Random.Range(0, spawnSpots.Length);
            Instantiate(duck, spawnSpots[randPos].position, Quaternion.identity);
            timeBtwSpawns = startTimeBtwSpawns;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so ive updated it but under alive is highlighted red saying grannycontroller does not contain a definition for 'alive' public bool IsAlive() { return this.alive; }

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use a boolean or a state, whatever you prefer and just avoid creating new Instances.

Could be something like this in SpawnerController create a boolean called for example spawneable, this boolean could be public and you can modify it from the player death to false and in that way you stops the cloning:

```
void Update()
{

    if (timeBtwSpawns <= 0)
    {
        if(spawneable)
        {
           int randPos = Random.Range(0, spawnSpots.Length);
           Instantiate(duck, spawnSpots[randPos].position, Quaternion.identity);
           timeBtwSpawns = startTimeBtwSpawns;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        timeBtwSpawns -= Time.deltaTime;
    }

}
```

This is the easiest way I can imagine, not the best way but you got it working in a few lines.

Comment: So ive dont that but now the ducks arent spawning

Comment: No you have to change `spawneable` into `true` when it the ducks should be spawing =)

Comment: ive done that can you help please ive edited my code above.

Comment: @JamesO'Hanlon He's saying you need something like "public bool isDead" on the player that defaults to false but gets set to true when it dies. Then instead of "If (spawnable)" you can put "If (!Player.isDead)" since you already grabbed the player instance.

Answer (score 0):

Create method `IsAlive()` inside GrannyController script that returns alive/dead (true/false).

```
public bool IsAlive()
{
    return this.health > 0;
}
```

And here is updated Spawner. Remember to assign game object with GrannyController script to SpawnerController object.

```
public class SpawnerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GrannyController player;
    public GameObject duck;
    public Transform[] spawnSpots;
    private float timeBtwSpawns;
    public float startTimeBtwSpawns;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        timeBtwSpawns = startTimeBtwSpawns;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(!player.IsAlive()) return; // Check if player is alive, stop if not

        timeBtwSpawns -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (timeBtwSpawns <= 0)
        {
            int randPos = Random.Range(0, spawnSpots.Length);
            Instantiate(duck, spawnSpots[randPos].position, Quaternion.identity);
            timeBtwSpawns = startTimeBtwSpawns;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: still getting an error ive updated to what you said and still an error please be patient. can you have a look at the updated code above

Comment: Updated `IsAlive`.

Comment: so ive updated it but under alive is highlighted red saying grannycontroller does not contain a definition for 'alive'                                                                     
 public bool IsAlive()
    {
        return this.alive;
    }

Comment: It's working, you are just doing it wrong. Learn about Unity and C#, copy-paste won't help you.

Comment: its for a project due tomorrow can you just point where im going wrong the error is NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
SpawnerController.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/SpawnerController.cs:22) ill update my code so maybe you can see. sorry

Comment: If you could just READ then you would have no errors.

Comment: What @Oen44 means in that message is that you must set the `player` from the inspector.